# Java - Printing a class

Tags: java, arrays, methods, tostring

If I have an array of objects which have a toString method and I print the array using a for loop (e.g.: simply `array[i]` to reach the objects and carry out `System.out.println(array[i])`) will the toString method be invoked automatically? It seems to be but I just want to check this is what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it will.**

The advantage, in fact, of doing this over implicitly calling `.toString()` is that nulls are handled without throwing an exception.  If `array[i]` is `null`, `then System.out.println(array[i])` will print `null` where `System.out.println(array[i].toString())` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

This is because the `System.out.println(object)` method calls `System.out.print(object)` which calls `String.valueOf(object)` which in turn calls `object.toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it certainly will.

Here are some API descriptions of how `println(Object)` and `print(Object)` methods work.

[println(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29)

[print(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29)